# How to pass parameters to dot layout engine using c++ graphviz library?

Tags: c++, graphviz

When run my c++ program, it breaks down with an error that tells -Gcharset=latin1 is wanted for layout engine. 
Then how to pass the parameter to it when calling gvLayout(context, graph, "dot")?

Comment: Did you save the file as UTF-8?

Comment: No, I generate the graph by graphviz c++ library, not from a dot file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`agsafeset`](http://www.graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/development/doxygen/html/attribs_8c.html#acc1333bd692dea2cf05882f9f610c3c3) for setting the correct character encoding, for instance:

```
agsafeset(graph,"charset","Latin1","");
```